# SQL Loader - Actual length exceeds maximum

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I tried loading data into table using sql loader.

The log shows actual length of the string is 101 where as 100 is maximum(Rejects the record).But when i checked ,I found the length is 99.

data type of the string is varchar2(100) in table

I didnt specify anything about length in control file

What would be the exact problem?

Comment: Are there multibyte characters in the string, and the column is defined as 100 byte rather than 100 char? Otherwise you'd have to show us the data.

Comment: ½ is this a multibyte character? I found this char on rejected record..Can u pls elaborate about multibyte charaters?

Answer (score 4):

Your data value only has 99 characters, but it seems some are [multibyte characters](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch2charset.htm#NLSPG169) - from a comment at least one is the symbol `½`.

There are two related way to see this behaviour, depending on how your table is defined and what is in your control file.

You're probably seeing the effect of [character length semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch2charset.htm#GUID-B3C74175-7F77-49A6-9CC9-1F6F70F3A69D). Your column is defined as 100 *bytes*; you're trying to insert 99 *characters*, but as some characters require multiple bytes for storage, the total number of bytes required for your string is 101 - too many for the column definition.

You can see that effect here:

```
create table t42 (str varchar2(10 byte));
```

Then if I have a data file with one row that has a multibyte character:

```
This is 10
This is 9½
```

and a simple control file:

```
LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET UTF8
TRUNCATE INTO TABLE T42
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
  STR
)
```

Then trying to load that gets:

```
Record 2: Rejected - Error on table T42, column STR.
ORA-12899: value too large for column "MYSCHEMA"."T42"."STR" (actual: 11, maximum: 10)

Total logical records read:             2
Total logical records rejected:         1
```

If I recreate my table with character semantics:

drop table t42 purge;
create table t42 (str varchar2(10 char));

then loading with the same data and control file now gets no errors, and:

```
Total logical records read:             2
Total logical records rejected:         0
```

However, even when the table is defined with character semantics, you could still see this; if I remove the line `CHARACTERSET UTF8` then my environment defaults (via NLS_LANG, which happens to set my character set to WE8ISO8859P1) leads to a character set mismatch and I again see:

```
Record 2: Rejected - Error on table T42, column STR.
ORA-12899: value too large for column "STACKOVERFLOW"."T42"."STR" (actual: 11, maximum: 10)
```

(Without that control file line, and with byte semantics for the column, the error reports actual length as 13 not 11).

So you need the table to be defined to hold the maximum number of *characters* you expect, **and** you need the control file to specify the character set if your NLS_LANG is defaulting it to something that doesn't match the database character set.

---

You can see the default semantics a new table will get by querying, for the database default and your current session default:

```
select value from nls_database_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS';
select value from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS';
```

For an existing table you can check which was used by looking at the `user_tab_columns.char_used` column, which will be B for byte semantics and C for character semantics.

Comment: Thanks alex! I have 3 rejected records out of that two record has ½ .I checked lengthb(str) for those two records it showed 102 byted.I removed the ½ and tried loading data got loaded successfully.. where as when i check the third record it does not have any special character.lengthb(third record) gives 100 bytes... what will be the reason for rejecting third record?

Comment: I don't know, what error did that get in the SQL\*Loader log file?

Comment: ORA-12899: value too large for column (actual: 101, maximum: 100)

Comment: 'HAJRAHS ALIRTSUDNI 1, HAJRAHS  DNIHEB ALWAHDA ROAD,  DEHS # 91 - DARAB BEERLAKA  NEDOW YB  DEMMAHOM' This is the rejected record

Comment: OK, so that's reporting 101 bytes; however you copied and pasted it to do the `lengthb()` check seems to have modified it. That string is only 95 though? I would guess that in the problem value you have a character that looks normal but actually isn't - the # could be a sharp sign, or you might have odd quote marks, or accents, or something. If you can get the actual value - so `lengthb` does say 101 - you can use the `dump()` function to see the actual character code points. Also check the DB, file, environment and control file character sets make sense together.